# How can I prevent UI thread from going on until password input is right

Tags: android, dialog, listener, ui-thread

I am writing an Android file viewer to provided for the host app, our viewer is a fragment , and host app use newinstance to use our fragment. Some codes are as below:

```
newInstance () {
......
openfile();
return fragment;
}

openfile() {
......
if(ispasswordfile) {
    showPasswordInputDialog;
    mpassword = .;
    mpagecount = ..;
    ......;
    return errorcode;
} else {
    .......
}
}

 showPasswordDialog() {
     ......
     dialog.show();
     EditText edittext = dialog.findViewById(...);
     edittext.addListener(){
         override
         public boolean action....{
             .......
             if(password is right) {
                 .....
             }
         }
     };
```

My question is when dialog input password is right and then execute the sentences after showPasswordInputDialog. These codes are all running in UI thread, and listener need to change the UI if password is wrong, so I cannot pause the UI thread. So are there any ways to set a barrier between showPasswordInputDialog; and mpassword = .; And when the password is right I will remove the barrier and let the UI thread going down.
I try to use a while loop it does not work. And I cannot add actions in the listener when password is right, because I want to return the fragment by newInstance.

This has bothered me a long time, and help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to think that as an event based execution. So don't place the

> mpassword = .;

below the show dialog method. Now in the text change listener, on each and every change just check whether it is the right password or not. Then if the password is correct, then dismiss the dialog and set the password

```
if(password is right) {
   mpassword = .; //Then continue your work from here or call other method.
}
```

There is no need to block main thread.

Let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think you are right, put the mpassword in the listener function when password is right, but my question is if I call a callback function to inform the host app that password is right, how can it detect it and reopen the fragment.

Comment: What do you mean by reopening the fragment, Which fragment, the same fragment where you open the password dialog?? or other fragment in the same activity, Can you explain me the architecture clearly??

Answer (score 0):

> So are there any ways to set a barrier between showPasswordInputDialog; and mpassword = .;

No, sorry.

Comment: So there is no solution to my question?

Comment: @shaopingwang: Correct. Android's widget-based UI framework, like most modern UI frameworks, works on an event-driven basis.

Comment: I think when the input is right and then do the later job is a normal, so how does it implement in other android app?

Comment: @shaopingwang: The work ("the later job") gets triggered by a callback attached to the dialog, for example. This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), books on Android app development, etc.

Comment: I create a dialog class implements Dialog, so is it helpful using AlertDialog?

Comment: @shaopingwang: I would recommend that you use `AlertDialog` (or perhaps not a dialog at all, but do something else instead). It is possible to use `Dialog`, but that is a lower-level API and is not particularly well-documented.

Comment: @shaopingwang: I do not know what you mean by "bind UI thread".

Comment: I think listener on edittext is runnig on the other thread, and I wonder are there any solution to let UI thread do this listener.

Comment: @shaopingwang: In Java, objects, like a listener, do not run on threads. Methods run on threads.

Answer (score 0):

Put whatever work that needs to be done in `if(password is right)` block or use some sort of flag to know if the password is true and use it in `openfile()`.

Comment: Yes the difficult thing is how to how to detect the tag in openfile() , I use while but it will crash the thread.